# Why does the argument use an address of a pointer here?

Tags: c, pointers

I found an string buffer implemented in C here (https://sites.google.com/site/rickcreamer/Home/cc/c-implementation-of-stringbuffer-functionality). There is a function called **dispose()**, one of whose argument is an address of a pointer:

```
void dispose( SB **sb, int freeStrings ) {
    if ( !sb || !*sb || !(*sb)->ptrList )
        return; /* TODO: Decide if should abort here or take other action */
    if ( freeStrings ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < (*sb)->count; ++i )
            free( (*sb)->ptrList[ i ] );
    }
    free( (*sb)->ptrList );
    free( *sb );
    *sb = 0; /* Set value of pointer to zero */
}
```

I cannot understand why its first argument is the address of the pointer, rather than the pointer. What I would convert the function to is:

```
void dispose( SB *sb, int freeStrings ) {
    if ( !sb || !sb->ptrList )
        return; /* TODO: Decide if should abort here or take other action */
    if ( freeStrings ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < sb->count; ++i )
            free( sb->ptrList[ i ] );
    }
    free( sb->ptrList );
    free( sb );
    sb = 0; /* Set value of pointer to zero */
}
```

Do I miss something here?

Comment: Look the last line of original code `*sb = 0; /* Set value of pointer to zero */` setting to NULL the pointer which address has been passed to the function. Tells you something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this prevents dangling pointers. Although it should be

```
*sb = NULL;
```

instead.

This way, after calling `dispose(&sb)` you can check if `sb == NULL` prior to dereferencing it and prevent dereferencing a pointer that has been freed.

And in your case, `sb = 0` has no effect because you never use `sb` after that.

Also, being `freeStrings` a paramter I would argue that this is a flaw design. If the author wanted to have dual `free()` behavior which is already bad, they should have had a `freeStrings` member in the structure and then there would be a lot of control over whether the strings were owned by the structure or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `sb = 0; /* Set value of pointer to zero */` actually sets the value of the *local* variable `sb` to zero. That's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is variable type just like `int, float`, etc... So, if you want to change it's value in a function, you have to pass a reference to it as an argument. That is why you have `**sb` as parameter instead of `*sb`.